# How do I need to wire these switches to finish the circuit?

Tags: electrical, switch

Recently started upgrading switches and outlets in my home. I have two switches in one box. The switch on the left is a single switch that controls the back porch light. The switch to the right is a common switch that turns on an inside light. Originally the two were connected by a single black wire.

I foolishly cut all the wires and cannot get the lights to work. It’s not the breaker, it’s the wiring. At this point I feel like I’ve tried every combination. Any ideas on what I can do?

There are 4 black wires, a white and a red.

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/f7e5ED0

Picture for reference!

Comment: Which wires are on the black screw vs the 2 brass screws?

Comment: Right now it’s a red wire and a black wire.

Comment: Did tge old switch have 4 screws besides ground?